# Why don't generic types work with inheritance in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, invariants, covariant

So here's the code:

```
package week4
object expr {
  abstract class Expr[T] {
    def eval:T = this match {
      case Number(x)   => x
      case Sum(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
    }
    def show: String = this match {
      case Number(x)   => "" + x
      case Sum(e1, e2) => "(" + e1.show + "+" + e2.show + ")"
    }
  }
  case class Number[T](val value: T) extends Expr {
  }
  case class Sum[T](val e1: Expr[T], val e2: Expr[T]) extends Expr {
  }
}
```

except I get the error on all for case comparisons that:

> constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : week4.expr.Number[T(in class Number)] required: week4.expr.Expr[T(in
>   class Expr)] Note: Nothing <: T (and week4.expr.Number[T] <:
>   week4.expr.Expr[Nothing]), but class Expr is invariant in type T. You
>   may wish to define T as +T instead.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If the provided answer is valid, it would be nice if you could mark it as accepted. :-)

Comment: Took my sweet time.

Comment: Better late than never. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are mainly two errors in your code:

- When extending `Expr` you forgot to pass the type parameter
- In the `Sum` branch of your pattern matching you are trying to sum two `T`s, without giving enough evidence to the compiler of the fact that the `+` operator is defined on the type `T`.

Here is a revised solution that works:

```
object expr {

  abstract class Expr[T](implicit evidence: Numeric[T]) {
    def eval: T = this match {
      case Number(x)   => x
      case Sum(e1, e2) => evidence.plus(e1.eval, e2.eval)
    }
    def show: String = this match {
      case Number(x)   => "" + x
      case Sum(e1, e2) => "(" + e1.show + "+" + e2.show + ")"
    }
  }

  case class Number[T : Numeric](val value: T) extends Expr[T]

  case class Sum[T : Numeric](val e1: Expr[T], val e2: Expr[T]) extends Expr[T]

}
```

Here is an example run in the Scala shell:

```
scala> import expr._
import expr._

scala> Sum(Sum(Number(2), Number(3)), Number(4))
expression: expr.Sum[Int] = Sum(Sum(Number(2),Number(3)),Number(4))

scala> println(expression.show + " = " + expression.eval)
((2+3)+4) = 9
```

I'm sure the missing type parameter for the type constructor `Expr` is just a distraction and it doesn't need further explanation.

The code in my example introduces an implicit parameter `evidence` and the usage of the `Numeric` type class. In Scala, a type class is a pattern that leverages traits and implicit parameters to define capabilities for classes with a certain degree of flexibility.

In order to sum two generic values, the compiler has to have a way to know that the two `T`s know how be summed. However the numeric types are not in a type hierarchy that can be leveraged by saying that `T` is a subtype of an hypothetic class `Number` (by writing something like `abstract class Expr[T <: Number]`).

The Scala standard library however has introduced the `Numeric` type class, which is basically a trait that defines a set of operations that make sense for all numeric types (hence the name). The `plus` method is a left unimplemented for whoever wants to adhere to this trait.

The Scala standard library implements this traits for various numeric types, thus allowing you to effortlessly use this same generic implementation with various types.

Here is an example:

```
scala> val expression = Sum(Sum(Number(2.0), Number(3.0)), Number(4.0))
expression: expr.Sum[Double] = Sum(Sum(Number(2.0),Number(3.0)),Number(4.0))

scala> println(expression.show + " = " + expression.eval)
((2.0+3.0)+4.0) = 9.0
```

Specifying an implicit evidence like this can be done explicitly (as in `abstract class Expr[T](implicit evidence: Numeric[T])`) or by using the so called "context bound" notation (as in `case class Number[T : Numeric]`), which is basically syntactic sugar for the explicit variant that foregoes to explicitly reference a type class instance. I used the explicit variant in the first case because I needed to reference the type class instance in my code to actually sum the two values (`evidence.plus(e1.eval, e2.eval)`) but I used the "context bound" notation in the latter case as I feel it more natural and readable.

If you so wish, you can also implement `Numeric[T]` for your own classes (e.g.: `Numeric[Rational]`) without having to deal with a static type hierarchy.

This of course is a very rushed explanation of type classes: for a more thorough explanation I suggest you this very good [blog post](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) on the topic.

Comment: Would also suggest reading up on type variance in addition to just type classes.

Comment: @3jckd absolutely, it can become a pretty important topic when dealing with type hierarchies. If you happen to read what type variance is and end up not understanding it, this image is a personal favorite of mine that may come to help: https://twitter.com/stefanobaghino/status/597016186820423680

Comment: The `new` keyword can be omitted when instantiating case classes like `Sum` and `Number`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @isaias-b You're totally right, since the compiler generates a companion objects for case classes, with the `apply` method as a shortcut for the constructor. Thanks for the tip, I'll edit the reply right away.